# How to speed up robocopy

Tags: windows, windows-7, performance, speed, robocopy

I'm working with a Windows-7 computer, who needs to copy a lot of small files from the network (NAS). I used to do this using `xcopy` command, but due to a file lock problem, I've decided to start working with `robocopy`, using following parameters:

```
robocopy \\nas\<subdir>\ <destination>\ /E /R:3 /V /FP
```

I have the impression that the performance has decreased severely, but as I don't have any logs of the previous situation (using `xcopy`), I'm not really sure.

Can I add any flags which would increase the performance of the `robocopy` command?

Comment: A must is /NP and /MT. I use /MT:64. Do not use /NOOFFLOAD or /TEE. When using /LOG, you must add /NP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Can I add any options to increase the performance of the `robocopy` command?

The following options will change the performance of `robocopy`:

> - `/J` : Copy using unbuffered I/O (recommended for large files).
> - `/NOOFFLOAD` : Copy files without using the [Windows Copy Offload](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh831628(v=ws.11)) mechanism.
> - `/R:n` : Number of Retries on failed copies - default is 1 million.
> - `/W:n` : Wait time between retries - default is 30 seconds.
> - `/REG` : Save `/R:n` and `/W:n` in the Registry as default settings.
> - `/MT[:n]` : Multithreaded copying, n = no. of threads to use (1-128)
>
>   default = 8 threads, not compatible with `/IPG` and `/EFSRAW`.
>
>   The use of `/LOG` is recommended for better performance.

Source - [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) - Robust File and Folder Copy.